# Unable to find property CurrentValues on EntityEntry<T> object that returned by DbContext.Entry<T> method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

*For one who miss question tags - it is all about **EntityFramework 7** (beta8)*

Main question is in subject.

Btw, all I need is shortcut method that allows me to set entity properties using another entity of same type (just like in example code below):

```
dbContext.Entry(someAttachedEntity)
    .CurrentValues
    .SetValues(someSrcObject);
```

It seems like my problem is connected with return value type of DbContext.Entry<T> method: in EF6 it was DbEntityEntry<T>, but in EF7 it is EntityEntry<T> *(more abstract object?)*.

So, is it some breaking change or I just miss some dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [aspnet/EntityFramework#1999](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1999#issuecomment-94168803);

> we do not have anything like this planned for EF7 RTM but it sounds
>   like something we would consider adding in the future.

Comment: Ok, thanks :-) So, no suggestions on how to deal with that problem right now (except obvious and, actually, quite simple my-own-reflection-based solution)?